# How to permanently redirect port 80 to 8080 on OS X?

Tags: routing, osx-snow-leopard

On OS X 10.6 you do not have `iptables`, so what is the full solution for this permanently redirect all request sent to port 80 to another port, like 8080?

It has to be persistent.

Comment: I wanted to suggest `rinetd` because it is so simple I thought it would compile anywhere, but there does not seem to be a port to OS X, unfortunately...

Comment: I can't post this as an answer because this question is protected, but I've had great success using the built in Apache server to redirect to another port. Add the following to the end of  /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: `<Location />\nProxyPass http://localhost:8080/\n</Location>` (where `\n` is a newline), and then enable "Internet Sharing" in System Preferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use ipfw as in @bindbn's answer.  That's the general idea.

#### Persistence:

put your rules into a file :

```
/etc/ipfw.conf
```

add at  the very top of your file

```
flush
```

### Ensure that there are not leading or trailing whitespaces in any line.

add to /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.ipfw.plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.yourdomain.ipfw</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
      <string>-q</string>
      <string>/etc/ipfw.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Either reboot, or

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.yourdomain.ipfw.plist
```

the first time.

After that it is

```
launchctl load com.yourdomain.ipfw
```

Comment: Chinggsy,

I tried your method and everything runs but once it does I get an error in the console.

    3/30/11 4:07:01 PM com.apple.ipfw[342] Line 1: socket: Operation not permitted

The permissions on both files are set to root as the owner and the issue persists.  What am I missing?

peace

Comment: This article fixed that for me: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/why-am-i-getting-a-dubious-ownership-of-file-error-when-launch-agent-runs-my

Comment: Actually, this answer didn't work for some reason. This article did however: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/04/05/setting-up-ipfw-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: In OS X Yosemite `ipfw` has been removed. An alternative solution using `pf` has been posted [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/zhoutong/8adca7038639f0f5fb0e).

Answer (score 12):

Use ipfw(read http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10945451 http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10996939&#10996939)

```
ipfw add NUMBER fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80
```

or http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/

Comment: Thank but is missing something, this change is not persistent.

Comment: okay ,... place your plist in Launch agents not launch Daemon. amazing it worked for me.

Comment: 'NUMBER' is some sort of position in ipfw and should be replaced with an actual number