# Redirect localhost port to external ip and port

Tags: firewall, redirect, localhost

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

I have an app that is looking for a service hosted on localhost:9999, but I am hosting this service on a different server at 12.3.4.5:8000. How can I setup firewall rules, dns rules, or some other option, in order to **redirect all requests to localhost:9999 on my machine to go to 12.3.4.5:8000**?

I found many questions asking how to redirect requests to a domain to localhost, but that is the opposite of what I am looking for. I want to redirect requests from localhost to a domain (or ip):

I found this question when searching **but it is not the same question as I am asking**: [Can I specify a port in an entry in my /etc/hosts on OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/54357/can-i-specify-a-port-in-an-entry-in-my-etc-hosts-on-os-x) I also tried to use ifconfig and pfctl as in this answer to fit my case but I was unable to make it work: [iptables equivalent for mac os x](https://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x/673551#673551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to route TCP traffic and that your server has SSH access, you can use an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 9999:12.3.4.5:8000 remote-server-user@12.3.4.5
```

Then all traffic to localhost:9999 is tunneled to 12.3.4.5:8000