# How to configure server such that all XMPP traffic goes to Google Chat? (Google Apps vs Gmail)

Tags: g-suite, xmpp

I have an XMPP (Jabber) application which talks to jabber servers.

It works great with accounts on gmail.com, but does not work at all with accounts on Google Apps hosted web sites.

Google says this is because special SRV records need to be created for Google Apps domains which point the XMPP service directly at the Google XMPP servers, ref:

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143

However, I can't ask each user to add these 10 SRV records to their domain.

Is there a way that I can configure my server, either through DNS or firewall, or some other means, to use Google's XMPP server for all domains?  This would have the effect of making REAL jabber servers not work, but it would allow ALL Google Apps domains to interoperate with my program.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and a solution would be interesting to obtain, but PLEASE don't overwrite XMPP records for existing domains!  Only do so if there are no XMPP records otherwise!  Also, you best bet would probably be to modify the library that your client uses to talk to different jabber servers, to automatically fallback to google if none are found.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try substituting the SRV records from the point of view of your server using /etc/hosts ?
Either it works, or the protocol / google's implementation defends against that and you'll have no choice but to add the records to public DNS.

Comment: /etc/hosts is purely a name-to-IP mapping as far as I know.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/54357/can-i-specify-a-port-in-an-entry-in-my-etc-hosts-on-os-x

Comment: @Jonathan You're right, I missed that. I believe dnsmasq has support for srv records.